# Azure - Is it possible for global administrators to enforce per-subscription resource limits?

Tags: azure, delegation, resources, resource-management

My company is moving all its internal production and development servers to Azure, and needs a way to delegate administration while at the same time keeping track of resource usage; thus, we are going to create multiple subscriptions, one for core systems and one for each development project.

However, the management wants to make sure that if f.e. a project manager is granted administrative rights on a project-specific subscription, he doesn't create twenty A9 virtual machines and leave them running for three months; ideally, a resource limit should be imposed, so that he can create and manage his own VMs but he can't bankrupt the company with Azure bills.

Can this be achieved? How?

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your local Microsoft sales representative about having Azure usage attached to an Enterprise Agreement (EA). EA based customers have access to a different management portal experience that allows you to create/manage multiple subscriptions and set overall spending limits on those subscriptions. EA's also offer bulk pricing discounts that can (depending on the level of commitment) exceed what's available from pay-as-you-go and 6-12 fixed purchase plans.

Comment: We already have an Enterprise Agreement and can create multiple subscriptions. We are looking exactly for the way to set resource limits on them, but we can't seem to find it.